# Deciphering Stream reduce function

Tags: java, java-stream

Why are both `c1` and `c2` are not seen as two Strings but instead one `String` and one `Integer`?

```
Arrays.asList("duck","chicken","flamingo","pelican")
            .stream()
            .reduce(0,
                    (c1, c2) -> c1.length() + c2.length(),
                    (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
```

Comment: Did you read the [documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html)? What makes you think they would be the same type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *three* variations of the [**`reduce`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method, which differ by their signatures and return types. if you look at the overload for [**`reduce`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) which has this signature:

```
reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

As you can see from the method signature this overload of [**`reduce`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) has 3 parameters the *identity*, accumulator and a combiner. The identity value is the initial value you've passed into `reduce` i.e (`0`), we then have the accumulator which basically incorporates an additional element into a result and finally, the *combiner* whos job is to combine the two values provided.

so you ask:

> Why are both c1 and c2 are not seen as two Strings but instead one
>   String and one Integer?

The first argument to `BiFunction` is `U` which in your case is `Integer` so, therefore, the type used for the identity value *must* be the same type of the first argument as well as the return type of the accumulator function (`BiFunction`).

That aside, you'll need to change this:

```
(c1, c2) -> c1.length() + c2.length()
```

to this:

```
 (c1, c2) -> c1 + c2.length()
```

it's important to note that the combiner *function* `(s1, s2) -> s1 + s2` will not be called at all. Reason being that this specific overload was designed to be used with `parallelStream`, so in order for a combiner to work, a stream *must* be parallel. Otherwise, just the accumulator function will be called.

as an side, your full code can be simplified to:

```
int result = Stream.of("duck","chicken","flamingo","pelican")
                   .reduce(0,
                   (c1, c2) -> c1 + c2.length(),
                   (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
```

or even better if you want to avoid the overhead of boxing/unboxing of `reduce`:

```
int result = Stream.of("duck", "chicken", "flamingo", "pelican")
                   .mapToInt(String::length)
                   .sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are trying to do the following:

```
Arrays.asList("duck", "chicken", "flamingo", "pelican")
    .stream()
    .map(c -> c.length())
    .reduce((c1, c2) -> c1 + c2);
```

First, map every String to its length, basically doing the following transformation:

```
("duck", "chicken", "flamingo", "pelican") -> (4, 7, 8, 7)
```

Then, reduce that result by adding the values.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Why can it not be done as I have written it above?

Comment: Please see Aominè's answer. You are using an overloaded version of reduce, that probably is not doing what you want it to do.