# Chain of operations

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a interface that takes a string and returns a transformed string

I have some classes that will transform in different ways.
Is there any way in Java to create a stream of those classes and make a transformation of a string.

For example:

```
class MyClass implements MyOperation {
   String execute(String s) { return doSomething(s); }
}

class MyClass2 implements MyOperation {
   String execute(String s) { return doSomething(s); }
}

ArrayList<MyClass> operations = new ArrayList<>();

operations.add(new MyClass());
operations.add(new MyClass2());
...

operations.stream()...
```

Can I make a stream of that in order to make lots of transformations for a single string? I thought about `.reduce()` but it is strict about the data types.

Comment: You want to imitate Java [`Stream::map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method that takes a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)

Comment: First of all what’s weird to me is that you declare operations as an arraylist of MyClass and proceed to add a MyClass2 to it. Perhaps you meant to make it an arraylist of MyOperations? Secondly, yes you could for example make a wrapper class to store a string, make the stream sequential (if your operations don’t commute, otherwise parallel is fine), and use a foreach to replace the string with the result of the operation, but that’s not really what streams should be used for. Iterating over operations seems more appropriate here.

Comment: the `ArrayList<MyClass>` should be`ArrayList<MyOperation>` else the call to `operations.add(new MyClass2());` would yield a compilation error. Nevertheless, you're probably looking for this over of reduce --> `String result = operations.stream().reduce("myString", 
                (x, y) -> y.doSomething(x),
                (a, b) -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("unimplemented");
                });`

Answer (score 3):

Your classes all implement methods that transform a `String` to a `String`. In other words, they can be represented by a `Function<String,String>`. They can be combined as follows and applied on a single String:

```
List<Function<String,String>> ops = new ArrayList<> ();
ops.add (s -> s + "0"); // these lambda expressions can be replaced with your methods:
                        // for example - ops.add((new MyClass())::execute);
ops.add (s -> "1" + s);
ops.add (s -> s + " 2");
// here we combine them
Function<String,String> combined = 
    ops.stream ()
       .reduce (Function.identity(), Function::andThen);
// and here we apply them all on a String
System.out.println (combined.apply ("dididi"));
```

Output:

```
1dididi0 2
```

Comment: `((f1,f2)->f1.andThen (f2))` can be simplified to `(Function::andThen)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `ArrayList<MyClass>` should be `ArrayList<MyOperation>` else the call to `operations.add(new MyClass2());` would yield a compilation error.

That said you're looking for [this overload of `reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
String result = operations.stream().reduce("myString",
                (x, y) -> y.execute(x),
                (a, b) -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("unimplemented");
                });
```

- `"myString"` is the identity value.
- `(x, y) -> y.execute(x)` is the accumulator function to be applied.
- `(a, b) -> {...` is the combiner function used *only when the stream is parallel*. So you need not worry about it for a sequential stream.

  You may also want to read upon an answer I've posted a while back ["Deciphering Stream reduce function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47245348/deciphering-stream-reduce-function).

Comment: thank you for explaining the combiner function. the compiler gives confusing messages.

Comment: @JackFlamp you're more than welcome. what are those messages saying?

Comment: I was just testing to replace your throwing runtimeexception with `a.equals(b)` to see what the combiner is and the execute method says `The method execute(String) in the type General.MyOperation is not applicable for the arguments (U)`. The reduce says  `The method reduce(U, BiFunction<U,? super <MyOperation,U>, BinaryOperator<U>) in the type Stream<MyOperation> is not applicable for the arguments (String, (<no type> x, <no type> y) -> {}, (<no type> a, <no type> b) -> {})`

Comment: Btw, I changed your `y.doSomething(x)` to `y.execute(x)`. that seems more accurate and worked

Comment: @JackFlamp good shout, the method to be called is `execute` indeed as opposed to `doSomething`. as for the error message you've posted, you cannot just do `(a, b) -> a.equals(b)` because the combiner must return the same type as the identity value which is String in this case.

Comment: @JackFlamp you can test it with the combiner being --> `(a, b) -> {
                    System.out.println("Is this being called ?");
                    return "dummy";
                }`